# Using SolrJ REST-API to query data in a Spring Application

Tags: spring, web-applications, solr

I have solr running at `http://localhost:8983/solr/` . I have a Spring MVC app running at `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp`  . 
I would like to be able to Query only the solr data from my spring app. What is the best way to go about this? Does someone have a simple running example?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate Solr with Spring using [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).
SolrJ is the Solr Java Client Library which will allow you to query Solr and get back the results in java objects which you can use as Model objects with Spring MVC.
You can easily create a Repository which interacts with Solr using Solrj.
Also, secure the Solr Collections so that no one can access Solr from direct URL without authentication. 
The Solrj Client with the Spring MVC app can query SOlr with Authentication.

Comment: You can easily create a Repository which interacts with Solr using Solrj. How do I do this? I would love a simple example.

Comment: http://adeithzya.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/using-apache-solr-with-spring-framework/ Check the example. You can inject SolrServer Object into Repository/Service and use the same to query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [spring-data-solr](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr) to do so. It should integrate quite nicely into an existing spring MVC application.